# Use Cython Python hexadecimal bytes array to C char pointer

Tags: python, cython

I want to send hexadecimal byte array to C, which converted to char pointer.

This is code of Cython part.

```
cpdef c_write(int sd, char* buf, int len, unsigned int flags):
    send_message(sd, buf, len, flags)
```

And this is code which use the Cython function to implement tcp/ip.

```
class TcpClient:
def __init__(self, host, port, timeout, block):
    self._host = host
    self._port = port
    self._timeout = timeout
    self._block = block
    self._sock = libtcp.c_create_socket()

def connect(self):
    libtcp.c_connect(self._sock, self._host.encode(), self._port)

def disconnect(self):
    libtcp.c_disconnect(self._sock)

def recv(self):
    libtcp.c_start_process()

def send(self, buf):
    libtcp.c_write(self._sock, buf, len(buf), 0)

def register_recv_message_callback(self, py_func):
    libtcp.c_register_recv_message_callback(self._sock, py_func)

client = TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 2000, 10, True)
client.connect()
client.send("abc".encode())
```

When I send the "abc" it works well. But when I send the hexadecimal array like:

```
b'\x02\x00\x08\x00'
```

It will just receive 1 length of array. May be it caused by the slash '\'.

So How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this just C ignoring then `len` parameter and assuming the first 0 terminates the string?

Comment: Yes. right!!! If I try to change the bytes like '\\x02\\x00\\x08\\x00', it will be ok

Comment: Now I know where the problem caused. It just caused by printf in c. I use pritf("%s") to print out the hexadecimal array so, it just print the first character :( .